# Javascript single quote replace is being ignored

Tags: javascript, photoshop, quote, photoshop-script

I'm writing a Photoshop Javascript script file.  For all intents and purposes, this script when ran replicates a specific text layer several times.  If the original text layer contains an apostrophe, the replicated instances replace the apostrophe with a square block.  So "It's" becomes "It[]s" (obviously not brackets, but the square block.)

Here is the code:

```
titleLayer = al.textItem.contents;

newTitleLayer = titleLayer.replace("'", "\'");
alert(newTitleLayer); // At this point, this works:  "It's"

persistentSetting.putData(0,newTitleLayer);
app.putCustomOptions("text_contents4",persistentSetting,true);

alert(persistentSetting.getData(0)); // At this point, it does not.  It shows the square. "It[]s"
```

I know this has to be a simple issue, I've just never encountered this before.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you replace an apostrophe with an apostrophe? Does it output correctly if you omit the replace at all?

Comment: do you habe an actual sample page for us? Can you reproduce this with jsfiddle? Because it sounds more like an character encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want

```
newTitleLayer = titleLayer.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
//                                 ^^^^   ^
//    regex to match *all* apostrohpes     escape the backslash
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives me the same issue, as seen here:
http://i.imgur.com/qiQ4nnZ.png

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me is:

persistentSetting.getData(0).replace("EM", "'");  // It's not actually EM, but that's the little code that JS shows in my editor when I copied and pasted that special block [] character in.

Thanks for the help.